# ASP.NET MVC app redirects to localhost instead of app URI after Active Directory login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've created a multi tenant ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio, and after testing it on `localhost`, I publishing the app to Azure, went to the Azure portal and changed the app home page uri and response uri to

```
http:/{appname}.azurewebsites.net
```

while also adding

```
PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http:/{appname}.azurewebsites.net"
```

in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` inside `Startup.auth.cs`.

The problem is, when I try to access the published app, I get redirected to `https://localhost:xxxxx` after logging in, the same `localhost` port VS assigned automatically when creating the project.

Is there some other place I need to add the `http:/{appname}.azurewebsites.net` Uri for my application to redirect to the correct place?

EDIT: In my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="ida:ClientId" value="{Guid}" />
        <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
        <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="{secret}" />
        <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="http://{appname}.azurewebsites.net" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In my startup.auth.cs file:
private static string clientId =

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
private string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
private string resourceEndPoint = "https://manage.office.com";
private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
private string authority = aadInstance + "common";
private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) => 
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    var code = context.Code;

                    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                    string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                    string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, resourceEndPoint);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                    context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you check the fiddler traces. Seems that the `RedirectUri` is still pointing to localhost instead of the address you want to intent.

Comment: Please post the ConfigureAuth method which would help to understand how you have configured various AAD properties has setup while configuration.

Comment: @user1672994 Sorry for the late response, I'm posting the configure auth as an edit, but it's pretty much the default method made by VS when the project is created + the PostLogoutRedirectUri added in.

Comment: You should set the `RedirectUri` property of `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` so that after authentication browser redirects to set redirectUri page.

Comment: Oh crap I feel dumb now. Can't believe I missed that property when going over the documentation... Thanks for the help

Comment: I'll post the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the `RedirectUri` property of `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` object.

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedrirectUri = <<Redirect Uri>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Reply URLs may need to be adjusted in the https://portal.azure.com site under Azure Active Directory > App registrations > Application ID GUID > Settings > Reply URLs > Save as outlined in this document also: [Azure App Service error: AADSTS50011](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2018/01/30/azure-app-service-error-aadsts50011-the-reply-address-http-azurewebsites-netsignin-oidc-does-not-match-the-reply-addresses-configured-for-the-application/)